# How can I extract data from a raster stack based on a list of lat long?

Tags: r, raster

I have a raster stack with 100+ files. And I want to extract the values from each file for particular lat-long locations. This gives me the list of values for one Lat-Long combination.

```
plist <- list.files(pattern = "\\.tif$", include.dirs = TRUE)
pstack <- stack(plist)
#levelplot(pstack)

for (i in 1:length(plist))
  t[i]=extract(pstack[[i]], 35,-90)
```

How can I do it for thousands of locations when I have the lat-long locations in a separate file/dataframe. There is a location ID that I want to preserve too in the final list:

```
Lat Long LocID
35 -90   001
35 -95   221
30 -95.4 226
31.5 - 90 776
```

My final objective is to have a dataframe of this type:

```
Lat Long LocID value
35 -90   001   0.5
35 -95   221   1.4
30 -95.4 226   2.5
31.5 - 90 776  4.5
```

Though if it is not possible to preserve the LocID, that's fine too.

One of the files: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ank4uxjbjk3chaz/new_conus.tif?dl=0

---

Testing a solution from comments:

```
latlong<-structure(list(lon = c(-71.506667, -71.506667, -71.506667, -71.215278, 
-71.215278, -71.215278, -71.215278, -71.215278, -71.215278, -71.215278
), lat = c(42.8575, 42.8575, 42.8575, 42.568056, 42.568056, 42.568056, 
42.568056, 42.568056, 42.568056, 42.568056)), .Names = c("lon", 
"lat"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
ext<-extract(pstack,latlong)
```

gives

> Error in UseMethod("extract_") :
> no applicable method for 'extract_' applied to an object of class "c('RasterStack', 'Raster', 'RasterStackBrick', 'BasicRaster')"

**Update #2:**

The error was because it was conflicting with another package. This works:

```
raster::extract(pstack,latlong)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the input data?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `extract` function in `raster` library. First you read in your data frame and select the `lon`, `lat` columns. Let's say you have `dataframe` `dat` and the raster stack of `pstack`

```
loc <- dat[,c("long", "lat")]
ext <- extract(pstack, loc)
new_d <- cbind(dat, ext) # bind the extracted values back to the previous dataframe
```

Comment: Could you please check the solution I have tested. I am getting an error: Error in UseMethod("extract_") : 
  no applicable method for 'extract_' applied to an object of class "c('RasterStack', 'Raster', 'RasterStackBrick', 'BasicRaster')"

Comment: Are you sure you are extracting the `lon, lat` coordinates from `raster stack`? Are you still getting errors?

Answer (score 1):

I don't usually work with this type of data, but how about this:

```
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

# coordinate data
coords <- read.table(text = 'Lat Long LocID
35 -90   001
35 -95   221
30 -95.4 226
31.5 -90 776', header = T)

# list of all files
plist <- c('~/Downloads/new_conus.tif', '~/Downloads/new_conus copy.tif')

# image stack
data.images <- stack(plist)

# make a master data frame containing all necessary data
data.master <- data.frame(file = rep(plist, each = nrow(coords)), file.id = rep(1:length(plist), each = nrow(coords)), coords)
```

At this point, we have a master data frame that looks like this:

```
                            file file.id  Lat  Long LocID
1      ~/Downloads/new_conus.tif       1 35.0 -90.0     1
2      ~/Downloads/new_conus.tif       1 35.0 -95.0   221
3      ~/Downloads/new_conus.tif       1 30.0 -95.4   226
4      ~/Downloads/new_conus.tif       1 31.5 -90.0   776
5 ~/Downloads/new_conus copy.tif       2 35.0 -90.0     1
6 ~/Downloads/new_conus copy.tif       2 35.0 -95.0   221
7 ~/Downloads/new_conus copy.tif       2 30.0 -95.4   226
8 ~/Downloads/new_conus copy.tif       2 31.5 -90.0   776
```

Now we just extract the value corresponding to the data in each row of the data frame:

```
# extract values for each row in the master data frame
data.master$value <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(data.master)) {
    data.master$value[i] <- with(data.master, extract(data.images[[file.id[i]]], Lat[i], Long[i]))
}

                            file file.id  Lat  Long LocID value
1      ~/Downloads/new_conus.tif       1 35.0 -90.0     1   255
2      ~/Downloads/new_conus.tif       1 35.0 -95.0   221   255
3      ~/Downloads/new_conus.tif       1 30.0 -95.4   226   259
4      ~/Downloads/new_conus.tif       1 31.5 -90.0   776   249
5 ~/Downloads/new_conus copy.tif       2 35.0 -90.0     1   255
6 ~/Downloads/new_conus copy.tif       2 35.0 -95.0   221   255
7 ~/Downloads/new_conus copy.tif       2 30.0 -95.4   226   259
8 ~/Downloads/new_conus copy.tif       2 31.5 -90.0   776   249
```